# Regex Giftcard number pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex for a giftcard number pattern in an application. I have this so far and it works fine:

`(?:5049\d{12}|6219\d{12})` = 5049123456789012

What I need to account for though is numbers that are separated by dashed or spaces like so:

5049-1234-5678-9012

5049 1234 5678 9012

Can I chain these patterns together or do I need to make separate for each type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most simple regex could be:

```
(?:(5049|6219)([ -]?\d{4}){3})

Explanation:
(5049|6219) - Will check for the '5049' or '6219' start
(x){3} - Will repeat the (x) 3 times
[ -]? - Will look for " " or "-", ? accepts it once or 0 times
\d{4} - Will look for a digit 4 times
```

A more detailed explanation and example can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/A46GJp/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use `(?:5049|6219)(?:[ -]?\d{4}){3}`

First, match one of the two leads. Then match 3 groups of 4 digits each, each group optionally preceded by space or dash.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SyjaT5/1) for demo, and also explains in more detail.

The above regex will also match if separators are mixed, e.g. `5049 1234-5678 9012`. If you don't want that, use

`(?:5049|6219)([ -]?)\d{4}(?:\1\d{4}){2}`   [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SyjaT5/2)

This captures the first separator, if any, and specifies that the following 2 groups must use that same separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(?:(504|621)9(\d{12}|(\-\d{4}){3}|(\s\d{4}){3}))
```

https://regex101.com/r/SyjaT5/6